# onConfigurationChanged called when i start activity in landscape，the window show about 1s later

Tags: android

`OnConfigurationChanged` called when i start activity in landscape，the window show about 1s later. i mean it cause a stuck, i guess the activity start in portrait and then change to landscape， but `oncreate()` only run once, and i cann't find where the orientation was set in the project.where may set the orientation? 
    Logs in "oncreate()" show that the orientation is portrait, but in fact the device is landscape indeed, when i delete the [android:theme="@style/notitle_theme"]
,the problem solved, i just want to know why.
i need you help my friend! Forgive my poor english.

```
<activity
      android:name="com.ppp.control.hor.addnw.SpeakerAddMoreActivity"
      android:theme="@style/notitle_theme"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
      <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

```js
<style name="notitle_theme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/activity_animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

```js
<style name="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your activity use android:screenOrientation=landscape  or portrait so it wont change only if you want to start activity with a selected orientation

```
 <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```